jest-pact in angular app with pact-version V3
We currently try to establish pact in our angular frontend. As a test framework we use jest, so we use the library jest-pact for it.
As we use Pact V4 and V3 in the backend system using pact-jvm, we wanted to use it here as well.
The services actually calling our backend are generated from our openapi-spec.
Unfortunately, we always get the following error:
 FAIL  src/app/pacts/foo.spec.pact.ts (6.818 s)
Pacts
  Pact between frontend and backend
    with 30000 ms timeout for Pact
      test-foo
        ✕ foo (5010 ms)

● Pacts › Pact between frontend and backend › with 30000 ms timeout for Pact › test-foo › foo

thrown: "Exceeded timeout of 5000 ms for a test.
Add a timeout value to this test to increase the timeout, if this is a long-running test. See https://jestjs.io/docs/api#testname-fn-timeout."

  24 |       });
  25 |
> 26 |       execute('foo', ({ url }) => {
     |       ^
  27 |         const spectator = createHttp();
  28 |         spectator.service.configuration.basePath = url;
  29 |         return spectator.service

  at context.<computed> (node_modules/zone.js/bundles/zone-testing.umd.js:492:43)
  at execute (node_modules/jest-pact/src/v3/index.ts:41:9)
  at src/app/pacts/foo.spec.pact.ts:26:7
  at node_modules/jest-pact/src/v3/index.ts:43:7
  at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/bundles/zone.umd.js:412:32)
  at ZoneImpl.run (node_modules/zone.js/bundles/zone.umd.js:147:47)
  at node_modules/zone.js/bundles/zone-testing.umd.js:426:37
  at context.<computed> (node_modules/zone.js/bundles/zone-testing.umd.js:474:43)
  at pactDescribe (node_modules/jest-pact/src/v3/index.ts:38:5)
  at src/app/pacts/foo.spec.pact.ts:12:5
  at node_modules/jest-pact/src/v3/index.ts:78:5
  at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/bundles/zone.umd.js:412:32)
  at ZoneImpl.run (node_modules/zone.js/bundles/zone.umd.js:147:47)
  at node_modules/zone.js/bundles/zone-testing.umd.js:426:37
  at context.<computed> (node_modules/zone.js/bundles/zone-testing.umd.js:474:43)
  at jestPactWrapper (node_modules/jest-pact/src/v3/index.ts:55:3)
  at node_modules/jest-pact/src/v3/index.ts:89:43
  at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/bundles/zone.umd.js:412:32)
  at ZoneImpl.run (node_modules/zone.js/bundles/zone.umd.js:147:47)
  at node_modules/zone.js/bundles/zone-testing.umd.js:426:37
  at context.<computed> (node_modules/zone.js/bundles/zone-testing.umd.js:474:43)
  at pactWith (node_modules/jest-pact/src/v3/index.ts:89:3)
  at src/app/pacts/foo.spec.pact.ts:11:11
  at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/bundles/zone.umd.js:412:32)
  at ZoneImpl.run (node_modules/zone.js/bundles/zone.umd.js:147:47)
  at node_modules/zone.js/bundles/zone-testing.umd.js:426:37
  at context.<computed> (node_modules/zone.js/bundles/zone-testing.umd.js:474:43)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/app/pacts/foo.spec.pact.ts:6:1)

● Pacts › Pact between frontend and backend › with 30000 ms timeout for Pact › test-foo › foo

Expected no open requests, found 1: GET http://127.0.0.1:62915/foo

  at _HttpClientTestingBackend.verify (node_modules/@angular/common/fesm2022/http/testing.mjs:298:19)
  at node_modules/@ngneat/spectator/fesm2022/ngneat-spectator.mjs:2347:51
  at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/bundles/zone.umd.js:412:32)
  at ProxyZoneSpec.Object.<anonymous>.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (node_modules/zone.js/bundles/zone-testing.umd.js:2164:43)
  at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/bundles/zone.umd.js:411:38)
  at ZoneImpl.run (node_modules/zone.js/bundles/zone.umd.js:147:47)
  at Object.wrappedFunc (node_modules/zone.js/bundles/zone-testing.umd.js:450:38)

My test project to show our problem can be found here
There is also a GitHub action showing the error here
Can someone help us figure out what we are doing wrong?
